# Is anyone familiar with EDsim?

Tags: 8051

I'm learning the basics of the microcontroller 8051 and I wrote a program that requires me to toggle a button situated in the ADC of the chip .
Since I don't have the board , I worked on a software called EdSim to toggle or do some settings in the virtual board .
I do have pins related to extern switches (P2.0 to P2.7) that I can use them .
But I can't modify the state of the switch that is situated in ADC (P3.2)

If anyone familiar with the EDSIM software ? Is it possible to toggle/untoggle P3.2 switch ?
Otherwise is there a better software to work on the 8051 micrcontroller ?

Comment: What do you mean by "ADC"? The common 8051 does not have an analog-digital-converter. -- There are several other simulators, please use your favorite web search engine. Recommendations are off-topic because they call for opinions.

Comment: @thebusybee   https://scontent.ftxl2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/129145710_396399004930036_5537763700011475185_n.png?_nc_cat=101&ccb=2&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_eui2=AeG1PMqSGIJtke1fCAa8CUaBBZs6RYWDA8sFmzpFhYMDy3jcyxAuZvSfu4zrAwVtND-uKobt9vU92-u-Nz8_HGNe&_nc_ohc=W8Q9-MActOYAX9yqwBC&_nc_ht=scontent.ftxl2-1.fna&oh=43c310b116c74ef4b8c86c9593a52cbe&oe=5FF06FE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the schematic, it seems that you have P3.2 connected to the INTR output of the external ADC.

And the [documentation of EdSim51](https://www.edsim51.com/simInstructions.html#switches) says:

> When the conversion is complete the INTR line goes low (and remains low until another conversion is initiated). This line is applied to the external 0 interrupt line, INT0. In this way, the 8051 can be interrupted by the completion of an ADC conversion.

So you need to initialize a conversion to get this line high, and when the conversion is done, it gets low again.